# Form get reloaded on submit reactjs

Tags: reactjs, forms

When I submit my form it gets reloaded, but when no file is selected, it doesn't get reload, just show me an error message 'No File Uploaded'.
It only gets reloaded when I submit the file.

I already used the e.preventDefault() to prevent reloading but it doesn't work.

Component Code

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const FileUpload = () => {
    const [file, setFile] = useState('');
    const [filename, setFilename] = useState('Choose File')
    const [uploadedFile, setUploadedFile] = useState({})

    const onChange = (e) => {
        setFile(e.target.files[0]);
        setFilename(e.target.files[0].name);
    }

    const onSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file);

        try {
            const res = await axios.post('/upload', formData, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                }
            })

            const { fileName, filePath } = res.data;

            setUploadedFile({ fileName, filePath });
            console.log(uploadedFile);
        } catch (err) {
            if (err.response.status === 500) {
                console.log("There was a problem with the server.");
            } else {
                console.log(err.response.data.msg);
            }
        }
    }

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                <div className="mb-3">
                    <label htmlFor="formFile" className="form-label">{filename}</label>
                    <input className="form-control" type="file" id="formFile" onChange={onChange} />
                </div>
                {/* <button type="submit" value="Upload" className="btn btn-primary w-100" /> */}
                <button className="btn btn-primary w-100" type="submit">Upload</button>
            </form>
        </Fragment>
    )
}

export default FileUpload
```

Anyone can please help me with this.

Comment: Your problem is that your form does not have the `action` attribute, i.e. `action="/link_to_some_page"`. This makes the form return to its default behavior, which is  sending the data to its current URL, which is why you are experiencing this behavior. You either need to specify where the form data should be sent, or prevent the default behavior by applying the `e.preventDefault()`propagation to the form's submit. Alternatively, you can utilize AJAX and send the data asynchronously.

Comment: I already applied `e.preventDefault()` to the submit event and I post data to my API URL using axios

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this code is in the async event handler,
`preventDefault` needs to be called synchronously to have
any effect at all.

You should call `e.persist()` before `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: I did as you said, still it get reload on submit 
e.persist();
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file);

Comment: @RishiPurwar Can you please upload it to condesandbox or something similar, that way it could be easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using submit button and form `onSubmit` You can just use a normal button and bind the submit handler to `onClick`

```
<form>
                <div className="mb-3">
                    <label htmlFor="formFile" className="form-label">{filename}</label>
                    <input className="form-control" type="file" id="formFile" onChange={onChange} />
                </div>
                {/* <button type="button" onClick={onSubmit} value="Upload" className="btn btn-primary w-100" /> */}
                <button className="btn btn-primary w-100" type="submit">Upload</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: Now, I did this
but still get reloaded
<button className="btn btn-primary w-100" onClick={onSubmit}>Upload</button>

Comment: you removed onSubmit from form element right?

Comment: Yes, I removed onSubmit event feom the form